# How to check if input string contains a letter in TCL/TK scripting?

Tags: scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a script which reads a list of integers from arguments and stores into a list then reverses its order.

I am trying to look for a way to check if the input argument contains a letter so I can halt the program and throw a error message. Then exit the script.

How can I check if a certain string has a letter? This letter can be uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
regexp {[[:alpha:]]} $string
```

returns 1 if there is a letter, 0 otherwise.

Documentation:
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)